# The meaning of kakemawaru 駆け回る

Tags: words

I have been encountering this word kakemawaru 駆け回る a few times. It means running around, If I understand well.
Does it mean only physically running around?
For example: kids are running around in the park.
Kodomotachi wa kouen de kakemawatteimasu.

Or can one also use it to express 'having a lot to do, I have been running around the city to do errands.' so that we are busy and we "run here and there" the whole day.

Thank you for your help in advance^^

Comment: I think this [dictionary entry](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E9%A7%86%E3%81%91%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B&dtype=3&dname=2ss&stype=0) pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thank you, you are right that entry clears it perfectly!:)

Comment: @DajkaLaszlo Perhaps now that you know the answer, you can post it as an answer to your own question!

Comment: Whoever is good with `擬声語`:  Can this be used interchangeably with `ドタバタする`?  If so, in what scenarios?

Answer (score 3):

As 'nkjt' supported me with a very good link, I wish to share its content that clears the issue I had with the word kakemawaru which is the following:

かけまわる 【駆け回る】

［１］【走り回る】run  around [back and forth, to and fro].（※runの代わりにrushを用いる方が迅速な動きを表わす）

```
    子供たちは庭を駆け回って（遊んで）いる
```

The children are running around [主に英 about] in the garden.

［２］【奔走する】（忙しい）be busy doing; with;（忙しく動き回っている）話 be on the run.

```
    彼は資金集めに駆け回っている
```

He is running around [主に英 about] raising funds./He is busy raising funds.

```
    うちのお父さんはいつも忙しく駆け回っている
```

My father's always on the run.

Comment: It looks like this answer could also be the answer to a very similar question a long time ago.
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5902/1328